# Where is You Tube application

Tags: iphone

My youtube app has disappeared from the screen but is still giving me update notifications and shows up in my list of apps to turn on data and such. When updates show, they will install but then the app icon does not appear on the screen and when I try to open it in the app store it does nothing. Frustrating!!! Please help :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please add relevant details to your question: iOS version (assuming it is iOS), what device are you using. Thanks!

Comment: Is this an actual Apple-branded iPhone or is it just an Android?

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall the app (via Settings) and then pull it again. If you still cannot see the icon, swipe your finger down from the center of the screen to open iPhone's Spotlight (search) and type youtube. App should appear.